# Get the name of the currently executing testing test?

Tags: go

In Go, how would I get the name of the currently executing test, the function name starting with `Test`, of the current test without passing it in manually?

Comment: You can find in the following link some approaches to get the function name: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742749/get-name-of-function-using-google-gos-reflection

Comment: You should consider changing the accepted answer as it seems there's a new way of doing this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use the `Name()` method:

```golang
func TestSomethingReallyCool(t *testing.T) {
    t.Logf("Test name is %s", t.Name())
}
```

Here's the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#B.Name) and here's the [code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.14/src/testing/testing.go#L591).

Comment: Seems like this might be new? Either way this should be the excepted answer now.

Comment: THIS is actually the answer

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question. When you define a test, you pass around a struct that represents the test itself:

```
func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
```

`testing.T` is defined as follows:

```
type T struct {
    common
    name          string    // Name of test.
    startParallel chan bool // Parallel tests will wait on this.
}
```

So the struct `t` has the name of the test in a field called `name`. However, for some reason, the name is not exported and there is no public accessor that will return it. Therefore, you can't access it directly.

There is a workaround. You can use the `reflect` package to access the unexported `name` and get the test name from `t`:

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(*t)
name := v.FieldByName("name")

// name == "TestSomething"
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but I was not able to find another reasonable solution to access `name` from the testing package.

Comment: Nice one. My method was to inspect the call tree, but your is much less prone to error, and will work from routines not rooted in Test callstack. https://github.com/anacrolix/missinggo/blob/master/testing.go#L12