# Is it possible get information about caller function in Golang?

Tags: go

Is it possible get information about caller function in Golang? For example if I have

```
func foo() {
    //Do something
}
func main() {
    foo() 
}
```

How can I get that `foo` has been called from `main`?
I'm able to this in other language (for example in C# I just need to use `CallerMemberName` class attribute)

Comment: yes, it's possible - see https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Callers

Comment: yes, but although it is possible it usually shows bad design decision. Except debug purpose it does not make sense. All necessary information should be passed as function arguments, or like closure variables.

Comment: For an example, check out how the stretchr/testify library does it: https://github.com/stretchr/testify/blob/v1.1.3/assert/assertions.go#L73

Answer (score 32, accepted):

expanding on my comment, here's some code that returns the current func's caller

```
import(
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func getFrame(skipFrames int) runtime.Frame {
    // We need the frame at index skipFrames+2, since we never want runtime.Callers and getFrame
    targetFrameIndex := skipFrames + 2

    // Set size to targetFrameIndex+2 to ensure we have room for one more caller than we need
    programCounters := make([]uintptr, targetFrameIndex+2)
    n := runtime.Callers(0, programCounters)

    frame := runtime.Frame{Function: "unknown"}
    if n > 0 {
        frames := runtime.CallersFrames(programCounters[:n])
        for more, frameIndex := true, 0; more && frameIndex <= targetFrameIndex; frameIndex++ {
            var frameCandidate runtime.Frame
            frameCandidate, more = frames.Next()
            if frameIndex == targetFrameIndex {
                frame = frameCandidate
            }
        }
    }

    return frame
}

// MyCaller returns the caller of the function that called it :)
func MyCaller() string {
        // Skip GetCallerFunctionName and the function to get the caller of
        return getFrame(2).Function
}

// foo calls MyCaller
func foo() {
    fmt.Println(MyCaller())
}

// bar is what we want to see in the output - it is our "caller"
func bar() {
    foo()
}

func main(){
    bar()
}
```

For more examples: https://play.golang.org/p/cv-SpkvexuM

Comment: I'm probably being daft, but why are you subtracting 1 from the fpc in `runtime.FuncForPC`?

Comment: @Femaref TBH I don't remember :) there shouldn't be a reason to, but this is copied off of a working piece of code.

Comment: @Femaref: Per the [godoc on runtime.Callers](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Callers), you would need to subtract because it "will normally return the file and line number of the instruction immediately following the call". The doc also suggests not using this function for this purpose, and instead using runtime.Frames.

Comment: Rather than use the result of runtime.Callers, runtime.CallersFrames should be used as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46289376/5250939
and described in the doc: https://godoc.org/runtime#Callers

Comment: @BoSunesen this answer predates CallersFrames, feel free to suggest an edit.

Answer (score 125):

You can use [`runtime.Caller`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller) for easily retrieving information about the caller:

```go
func Caller(skip int) (pc uintptr, file string, line int, ok bool)
```

---

**Example #1**: Print caller file name and line number: https://play.golang.org/p/cdO4Z4ApHS

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func foo() {
    _, file, no, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf("called from %s#%d\n", file, no)
    }
}

func main() {
    foo()
}
```

---

**Example #2:** Get more information with [`runtime.FuncForPC`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Func): https://play.golang.org/p/y8mpQq2mAv

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func foo() {
    pc, _, _, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
    details := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
    if ok && details != nil {
        fmt.Printf("called from %s\n", details.Name())
    }
}

func main() {
    foo()
}
```

Comment: This one should be the proper answer.

Comment: Is it possible to get the function parameter of the caller function?

Comment: I actively use this approach, but it should probably be modernized now that there are wrapped errors.