# Idea Intellij how to navigate to line from console's print statement

Tags: intellij-idea, go

There are various fmt.Println statements in my golang project which I run through Idea IntelliJ version 2016.3. Is there any way I navigate to the code from console's printed statements? I want know what code is printing the line [rinted on console.

Comment: fmt.Println prints bytes to a the stdout descriptor, so the only way to refer back to the file would be to print the file and line number in addition to the other text. You can [find these by examining the call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212985/is-it-possible-get-information-about-caller-function-in-golang) and add the to the message in a format that idea understands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend looking into the log package.
https://golang.org/pkg/log/

```
package main

import (
    "log"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
    log.Println("Hello world") // main.go:9: Hello world
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lQGW6P10fs

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but maybe help others

you can use `function, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(1)` to get where is the runtime, for example, you can use [this](https://github.com/sadeghpro/GoToError) project for your error