# How to get real file name by runtime.Caller called by anonymous function in different goroutine

Tags: go, callstack

I have this example code https://play.golang.org/p/c_2GECIcrW
What I expect **getFileName** will print out something like **main.go:11** but what I get is the **asm_amd64p32.s:1014**

What can I do to get the expect result in this case?
Can I archive that and still using anonymous function?

Comment: You can't. Sorry.

Comment: Not sure what it is you want with `shift`. Using `runtime.Caller(0)` will give you `"main.go:17"` inside anonymous function started as a new goroutine.

Comment: I want to get `main.go:11` (caller of getFileName)

Comment: See similar problem in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212985/is-it-possible-get-information-about-caller-function-in-golang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expectation is incorrect.

Let me paste your code here for ease of explanation:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    getFileName(1)
    time.Sleep(time.Hour)
}

func getFileName(shift int) {
    go func() {
        _, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(shift)
        if !ok {
            file = "???"
            line = 0
        } else {
            file = filepath.Base(file)
        }

        fmt.Printf("%s:%d", file, line)
    }()
}
```

Your anonymous function is running in a goroutine spawned by `getFileName`.

Each goroutine executes using its own call stack, even the goroutine spawned by `getFileName` starts with a fresh stack.

By invoking `runtime.Caller(skip int)` with a skip value greater than zero, you can walk through the stack frames of the current goroutine.

In your example:

- `runtime.Caller(0)` prints **main.go:17** because this is the line where `runtime.Caller()` is actually called,
- `runtime.Caller(1)` prints **asm_amd64p32.s:1014** because it is the top of the stack of the current goroutine,
- `runtime.Caller(x)` for any x > 1 returns with the boolean `ok` set to `false` because you're trying to access memory above the top of the stack.

If you're wondering what **asm_amd64p32.s:1014** represents, actually it corresponds to the [goexit](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.8/src/runtime/asm_amd64p32.s#L1014) assembly function of Go 1.8 (the Go Playground runs with the latest stable release of Go). Despite its name, the `goexit` function is always at the top of a goroutine stack: it invokes the goroutine entry point function and then clean up the stack after the function returns. The `goexit` implementation is architecture-specific, as it is most of the code that handles the details of the goroutines stack.

Back to your question, you cannot expect to see **main.go:11** mentioned in the stacktrace of the goroutine spawned by `getFileName`, because the main function is not in the stack at all. Don't spawn a goroutine, if you really need to print the stacktrace of the main function.

Having said that, there is something more to mention. The Go runtime actually stores additional information about where a goroutine has been spawned. The [debug.PrintStack()](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#PrintStack) function (which is in turn based on [runtime.Stack()](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Stack)) is able to print it out in a nicely formatted stacktrace:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "runtime/debug"
)

func main() {
    getFileName(1)
    time.Sleep(time.Hour)
}

func getFileName(shift int) {
    go func() {
        debug.PrintStack()
    }()
}
```

Output:

```
goroutine 5 [running]:
runtime/debug.Stack(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x80
runtime/debug.PrintStack()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:16 +0x20
main.getFileName.func1()
    /tmp/sandbox085104368/main.go:15 +0x20
created by main.getFileName
    /tmp/sandbox085104368/main.go:16 +0x40
```

Being all these details implementation-dependent and subject to change between different Go releases, there is - by design - no easy way to access them via the standard library. They're provided for debugging purposes and you, as a developer, should not rely on these information.