# Recover call stack when spawning goroutines

Tags: go, runtime, stack-trace

The following

```
func a() { b() }
func b() { c() }
func c() { d() }
func d() {
    pc := make([]uintptr, 10)
    n := runtime.Callers(1, pc)
    if n == 0 {
        return
    }

    frames := runtime.CallersFrames(pc[:n])

    for {
        frame, more := frames.Next()

        fmt.Println(frame.Function)

        if !more {
            break
        }
    }

}

func main() {
    a()
    // The reason for this sleep will become apparent in an incoming example
    // where we spawn a goroutine and do not explicitely wait for it to finish
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

outputs

```
main.d
main.c
main.b
main.a
main.main
runtime.main
runtime.goexit
```

as I expected. I am facing a situation where function `c` is called in a separate goroutine

```
func b() { go c() }
```

In such cas it outputs

```
main.d
main.c
runtime.goexit
```

, while I wished it to outpout the same as above.

Is there a solution to this problem? Maybe something to capture a call stack and pass it to function `d`? Note that performance will matter and I wish to avoid processing the stack beforehand as in my real life example, `d` might or might not need to trigger the call to runtime.Callers.

Comment: closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42692654/how-to-get-real-file-name-by-runtime-caller-called-by-anonymous-function-in-diff

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution. When you launch a function as another goroutine, it will run completely independent from the launching goroutine. The launcher may move on or completely finish / terminate. The "starting" stack is not retained for obvious reasons.

So unless you explicitly query and retain / pass the stack yourself when launching another goroutine, you'll lose it.

Note: it's possible to detect if a function is launched as a goroutine or not, and you could limit querying and retaining the stack only if so, and not in all cases. For details, see [Check if function is being called as goroutine or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56702183/check-if-function-is-being-called-as-goroutine-or-not/56702614#56702614).