# Name of current function

Tags: go

Is there a way to include the name of the current function I am in? I'd like to include it in my debug logs rather than hard coding the func name which is a pain after a while.

Thanks.

Comment: key skill of any good productive software developer is to master the art of google fu ... do a search on :   golang current function name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using `runtime.Callers`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func printFuncName() {
    fpcs := make([]uintptr, 1)

    // Skip 2 levels to get the caller
    n := runtime.Callers(2, fpcs)
    if n == 0 {
        fmt.Println("MSG: NO CALLER")
    }

    caller := runtime.FuncForPC(fpcs[0] - 1)
    if caller == nil {
        fmt.Println("MSG CALLER WAS NIL")
    }

    // Print the name of the function
    fmt.Println(caller.Name())
}

func foo() {
    printFuncName()
}

func main() {
    foo()
}
```

Outputs (package.function)

`main.foo`

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Rather than use the result of runtime.Callers, runtime.CallersFrames should be used as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46289376/5250939
and described in the doc: https://godoc.org/runtime#Callers

Comment: Why are we subtracting 1 from the PC here? I tested with(/out) the -1 but the result is weirdly the same:
`caller := runtime.FuncForPC(fpcs[0] - 1) `