# Equivalent of PHP __METHOD__ on golang

Tags: php, go

Is there a golang equivalent of PHP's magic `__METHOD__` constant, to get current running function?

Comment: how about `__FUNCTION__`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use reflection for that.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927660/how-to-get-the-current-function-name) answer maybe will help you. Remember that Go is a little bit different from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP also, instead of using magic constants/functions, we have the alternative of using **reflection**.

In Go, we can get details about currently running function by using bellow packages which are essentially using the reflection and runtime to get the required details,

> reflect
>
> runtime

We have it already answered in [How to get the name of a function in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052693/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-function-in-go)