# How to get a list of a struct's methods in Go?

Tags: go, reflection, go-reflect

I have a library in which there are both `Client` and `MockClient` structs which both implement the same `ClientInterface` interface. I would like to write unit tests to keep these structs in sync so that they not only just implement the interface, but so that `MockClient` has all of `Client`'s methods. To this end, I would like to get a list of a struct's methods in order to print an informative error message if one of the methods of `Client` is missing from `MockClient`.

I've tried adapting [How to get the name of a function in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052693/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-function-in-go) to this simplified example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "runtime"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (person *Person) GetName() string {
    return person.Name
}

func main() {
    person := Person{Name: "John Doe"}
    personValue := reflect.ValueOf(&person)

    for i := 0; i < personValue.NumMethod(); i++ {
        fmt.Println(runtime.FuncForPC(personValue.Method(i).Pointer()).Name())
    }
}
```

What I would like is for this script (shared at https://play.golang.org/p/HwvhEPfWI5I) to print `GetName`. However, instead, it prints

```
reflect.methodValueCall
```

How can I get this script to print the names of `*Person`'s methods?

Comment: Note that there's a compile-time test for "type *T or T implements interface I": `var _ I = (*T)(nil)` or `var _ I = T{}` (depending on whether you're testing `T` itself, or `*T`). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10498547/1256452 for details. That's not the same as listing the methods of the struct, of course; its usefulness is when you have defined an interface, and want to make sure that each implementation you wrote, implements that interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the type to get the method names:

```
t := reflect.TypeOf(&person)
for i := 0; i < t.NumMethod(); i++ {
    m := t.Method(i)
    fmt.Println(m.Name)
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5jBQEURqKSx).